# Convert specific time to UTC in python3 on AWs

Tags: date, python-3.6

I have some Streamsets code that looks like this:

```
${time:extractStringFromDateTZ(time:extractDateFromString(record:value('/receivedAt'), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"),"UTC","yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS")}
```

the `record:value('receivedAt')` value equals something like `'2019-08-28T21:50:30.292Z'`

It looks like the function is converting it to a date and then converting it to UTC. How do I do this in python3? Easiest way?

**EDIT**

I have some code but it's not working

```
 from datetime import datetime`
 ...
datetime.strptime(record["receivedAt"], time_format).astimezone("UTC")
```

where `record["receivedAt"] = '2019-08-28T21:50:30.292Z'` and `time_format = "%Y-%m-%d'T'%H:%M:%S.%f"`

my error: `ValueError: time data '2019-08-28T21:50:30.555Z' does not match format "%Y-%m-%d'T'%H:%M:%S.%f"`

Comment: You can't pass a string to `astimezone`, it needs to be a `tzinfo` object.

Comment: Note: `2019-08-28T21:50:30.292Z` is already a UTC datetime - that's what the `Z` means

Comment: the 'T' shouldn't be in quotes, god dammit.